# How to define edge for throttle binding behaviour in aurelia

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I have a custom attribute with a bindable property that I observe.

**HTML**

```
<div my-attribute="show.bind: isVisible & throttle: 300">
    <button>Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

**Attribute JS**

```
@customAttribute('my-attribute')
export class MyAttributeCustomAttribute{
    @bindable show;

    showChanged(newValue, oldValue) {  
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I only want the `showChanged` to be called after 300ms and to be throttled, so I want leading edge to be false and trailing edge to be true. I can achieve this in lodash/underscore with say a window resize event like so:

```
$(window).bind("resize", _.throttle(this.myFunction, 300, { 'leading': false }));
```

I tried achieving this using `debounce`, but my understanding is that it won't fire all the events just the last one within the time specified?

How can I achieve the same effect with a bindable property change? Is the binding behaviour approach through html incorrect and I should be doing it purely in JS?

Comment: If I am understanding what you want, I think you may need to create your own [custom binding behavior](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-binding-behaviors/8).

Comment: Yeah I think you are right, I'll create one and update the question with a solution. I just wanted to see if it came out of the box with the throttle binding behaviour

Comment: You can probably grab the code for the out-of-the-box throttle behavior and just add the feature using a `leading` argument. Please do post your solution.

Comment: Have a look at [Aurelia Task Queues](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/02/working-with-the-aurelia-task-queue/) for an Aurelia-way of using timers and tasks.